# Unable to install Check Point VPN Client under Unbunt 20.04

Tags: vpn

I am trying to install the CheckPoint VPN client under Ubuntu 20.04 but when I run the cshell_install.sh script I get the message error

Starting Mobile Access Portal Agent... /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/cshell/launcher: not found

Cannot start Mobile Access Portal Agent. Installation aborted.

Any help?

Best regards

Horacio Merovich

Comment: +1 I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I have written a bash cshell wrapper for Debian/Ubuntu that installs everything  automatically in a chroot setting.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro can you provide the script?

Comment: @LuísAssunção Hi, please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450131/vpn-ssl-network-extender-in-firefox and https://github.com/ruyrybeyro/chrootvpn

Answer (score 2):

The following libraries solved the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386 libx11-6:i386 libpam0g:i386
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked.